# Is it posible to add a list of data inside a data-table or step in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, bdd

```
    Scenario Outline: list of data in data table
       Given I have <numbers>
        When I sum its
        Then I should see <result>
    Examples:
       | numbers | result |
       | 1 2     | 3      |
       | 1 2 3   | 6      |
       | 1 2 3 4 | 10     |

    Scenario: list of data in a step
       Given I have numbers: 1, 2, 3
        When I sum its
        Then I should see 6
```

Notice that I use spaces in the first sample to add numbers, and in the second sample I use comma(,).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with either approach.

As described in https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines, Scenario Outline simply generates a set of scenarios using text substitution of the table values for the parameters. Based on the limited testing I did, it appears that Cucumber will ignore leading and trailing spaces in the table entries so, the `numbers` values will be the strings "1 2", "1 2 3", and "1 2 3 4" in this case.

Once the individual Scenarios are generated, then they are treated like any other scenario and matched with standard pattern matching.

The only thing to note is that your step definitions will need to account for whatever syntax you use.  In you case, while you can use either:

```
Given I have 1 2 3
```

or

```
Given I have numbers: 1, 2, 3
```

you're pattern(s) will need to accommodate whatever format(s) you use.

As for special characters, including single and double quotes, I assume pretty much anything can be used. The only part that would get tricky is if you wanted to include an end-of-line character in a `Given` line or a vertical bar in a data table. Just remember that "this is all just text" as far as your scenarios and step definitions are concerned. You just have to make sure your patterns match your examples.

Comment: Thanks for that. What about if I use double quote for strings for example: Given I have "1,2,3" or Given I have "1","2","3" which one is better?

Comment: And what about if I use double quotes and commas in datatable, eg: 
| numbers | 
| 1,2,3   | or
| numbers     |
| "1","2","3" | or
| numbers | 
| "1,2,3" | 
It is posible to use commas, and commas with double quotes in datatables?

Comment: "Which one is better" questions aren't really suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: Per the existing answer, it is possible to use commas in data tables.  See updated answer with respect to quotes.